# GDB: Run the breakpoint commands that were just created

Tags: debugging, gdb

A typical workflow for me in gdb:

- Set breakpoint
- Run until breakpoint
- Realize that I want to print out some variables at that breakpoint
- Use the 'command' command to create that behavior the NEXT time the breakpoint is hit

Is there a way to run the commands I just created for breakpoint N while the code is stopped at breakpoint N?

```
(gdb)
155             return candidate_parity + current_sub_traversal_parity == total_parity - other_dynamic_sub_traversal_parity;
(gdb) b 155
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7fffefdbc886: file blah.cpp, line 155.
(gdb) command 3
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 3, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>p total_parity
>p candidate_parity
>p current_sub_traversal_parity
>p other_dynamic_sub_traversal_parity
>end
(gdb) **** now I want something quick to run the commands for breakpoint 3 ****
```

Comment: Probably not what you want, but you can traverse the command line history when entering lines for `command`. It might also be possible to create a custom command with python to do exactly that.